# Fade in background image as user scrolls down to that div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a black background and I want to dynamically add/fade in a background image for that div only when the user has scrolled down to around the middle of that div.

HTML

```
div {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

JS (I really don't know what I'm doing. I tried my best.)

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $("html").scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > $(div).offset().top){
        $("div").css('background-image','url("img/background.jpg")').fadeIn();
    }
})
```

Am I sort of on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin:
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

Something like this should get the job done (not tested):

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function(event) {        
    $("div:in-viewport").each(function() {
      $(this).css('background-image','url("img/background.jpg")').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function isScrolledIntoView($elem) {
   var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

   var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
   var elemMiddle = elemTop + $elem.height()/2;
   return docViewBottom >= elemMiddle && docViewTop <= elemMiddle;
}
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $elem = $("div"); //or what element you like
   if(isScrolledIntoView($elem)){
      $elem.css('background-image','url("img/background.jpg")').fadeIn();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great but it doesn't really fade in. It just appears. I tried putting in a number like 2000 for `.fadeIn()` but nothing changed. Any ideas?